# Show established samba mounts

Tags: mount, samba

`showmount` only list me NFS mounts. I also want such a list for samba shares. How can this be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer should be a simple `mount -t <fs_type>`:

```
mount -t cifs
```

You will have the exact list of mounted `smb` filesystem (that is `cifs` type).

This option is available at least on Linux and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3):

If you used *Nautilus* to connect to the smb server, then the following command might be useful:

```
mount -v | grep -i 'gvfs'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had used nautilus to samba connect, `type smb` and `type cifs` shew nothing, but your command output `gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse`. Sadly, not really self-explanatory output ;-)

Answer (score 2):

On your server, command `smbstatus` lists the clients that are connected to the server.
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbstatus.1.html

Answer (score 1):

`mount` will show you all the mounts on your system, including smb mounts. You can easily find them just by looking at the list, but if you want to see only smb mounts, you can try something like:

```
mount -v | grep -i 'type smb'
```

or, if they are CIFS mounts not smbfs:

```
mount -v | grep -i 'type cifs'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mount -v | grep -i -e 'type smb' -e 'type cifs'
```